# jquery autocomplete broken when i using json get the source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JavaScript Code

```
$(function() {
    $('#itemname').autocomplete({source: "json-autocomplete.php"});
});
```

JSON

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemlist");
$arr = array();

while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj['name'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

my autocomplete can be use but it is display all of my source wherever what character is typing from me.

Comment: Sounds like your server either doesn't have PHP installed, or is misconfigured.

Comment: Please, post the output of your json_encode

Comment: ["Milo (1kg pack)","A Carton of Milo(1kg pack)","Milo (1kg pack)","A Carton of Milo(2kg pack)","Milo (1kg Tin)","A Carton of Milo(1kg Tin)","Milo (2kg Tin)","A Carton of Milo(2kg Tin)","Milo(5kg Tin)","A carton of Milo(5kg Tin)","Rice(5kg)","Rice(10kg)","Instant Noodles(regular pack 5*1)","Carton of Instant Noodles","Horlick(1kg pack)","A Carton of Horlick(1kg pack)","Horlick(2kg pack)","A Carton of Horlick(2kg pack)","Horlick(5kg Bottle)","Carton of Horlick(5kg Bottle)","Ribenna(1L)","Carton of Ribenna(1L)","Ribenna(2L)","Carton of Ribenna(2L)"] tis is the output from the json

Comment: but my autocomplete still can use ,but it is broken just like when i type ‘a’ ,but the autocomplete choose field also got ‘bee’ word for me to choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

If you are using jQuery UI Autocomplete, you need to implement $_GET['term'].
Look at the Developer Console on this page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote.

You can change this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792138/2408648.